Permission Set Not Applying to different profile user:
I created two profiles, employee and manager, which work on the same app. The manager profile has an extra object named Customer_Loan__c. The employee profile user cannot access that object. Using a permission set, I gave access to a particular Employee Profile user for that object so he could access it. But when I Logged in with the user I gave permission to, he couldn't see that object tab.

There can be two problem scenarios, either the tab is not visible or the object itself doesn’t have the access. Try the following to judge the scenario
Take a sample record of  Customer_Loan__c object, copy its url and try opening it with Employee profile. If the record opens up, the issue is with tab visibility , if it doesn’t it is the second scenario, where the profile does not have object access.
The Tab is not visible

The app the user is accessing might not have the Customer_Loan__c tab added to it. Check the Tab Settings in the permission set and keep it ‘Default On’
I am assuming that no separate apps are created of both the profiles. If separate apps are created, check in the App Manager that the Employee profile has access to the App where the tab of Customer_Loan__c is present.

Unable to access the object itself

If Customer_Loan__c is in Master-Detail Relation, the Employee profile has access to its parent object as well. Add both objects to the permission set.
Check the OWD settings, if the issue is related to particular records.
If you want only to share a particular record, you can try Manual Sharing as well.

I would suggest to take a sample record of  Customer_Loan__c object, copy its url and try opening it with Employee profile. It the record opens up, the issue is with tab visibility , if it doesn’t it is the second scenario where the object access itself is not present.
